# What are the protocol magic values for the preview and preprod test networks?

Tags: testnet, preprod

The cardano testnet has a protocol/testnet magic value of `1097911063`.

Where do I find this value for the preprod and preview test networks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the byron or shelley genesis files for `protocolMagic` or `networkMagic` respectively.

Genesis files for each network can be found here: https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments.html

Comment: `networkMagic` from the Shelley genesis files: Preview: `2`, Preprod: `1`